# Concatenating String in JQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, checkbox, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate a variable into a JQuery selector (which I understand to  be fairly straightforward), but I'm running into some interesting behavior. My code is supposed to uncheck certain radio selectors along a y-axis.

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    $("input[value='"+1+"']").each(function() {                     //<--
        $(this).on('change', function() {
            var that = this;
            $("input[value='"+1+"']").each(function() {             //<--
                if($(this).attr('name') != $(that).attr('name')) {
                    $(this).prop('checked', false);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Now, the code works as it is (selecting only inputs of value '1', that is) and works with the '1' included in the quotes as well. However, once I pass in either `i` or `i.toString()`, the code doesn't work. Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass in `i` to activate all my `inputs`. Is that going to be possible? I'm using JQuery from `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js`.

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="votes.php">
    <div style="border:black solid 1px;border-radius:5px;">
        <label>One</label>
        <input type="radio" name="one" value="1">
        <input type="radio" name="one" value="2">
        <input type="radio" name="one" value="3">
        <input type="radio" name="one" value="4">
    </div>
    <div style="border:black solid 1px;border-radius:5px;">
        <label>Two</label>
        <input type="radio" name="two" value="1">
        <input type="radio" name="two" value="2">
        <input type="radio" name="two" value="3">
        <input type="radio" name="two" value="4">
    </div>
    <div style="border:black solid 1px;border-radius:5px;">
        <label>Three</label>
        <input type="radio" name="three" value="1">
        <input type="radio" name="three" value="2">
        <input type="radio" name="three" value="3">
        <input type="radio" name="three" value="4">
    </div>
    <div style="border:black solid 1px;border-radius:5px;">
        <label>Four</label>
        <input type="radio" name="four" value="1">
        <input type="radio" name="four" value="2">
        <input type="radio" name="four" value="3">
        <input type="radio" name="four" value="4">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Show relevant HTML code.

Comment: radio, unselect??? Can't you use a radiogroup (ie. same `name` on the radio belonging together)?

Comment: I am grouping them: along the x-axis. It's a grid of radios where each x and y axis is unique.

Comment: can you elaborate more?  still it is confusing.. what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: 5 rows of 5 radio buttons, each radio valued 1-5 (for questionnaire purposes). Every rating (1-5) has to be unique on each selection (eg there can't be more than 1 value of the same type selected). I'm already using groups (names) to organize the individual selections' radio buttons (along the x-axis), so I have to use JS to manage the value selections (along the y-axis). Plug in the HTML and you'll see.

Comment: I added the full HTML form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic closure problem in JavaScript.  In your code, replacing `1` with `i` (the second `i`, that's in the event handler) would not work since those event handlers maintain an actual link to the **`i` variable itself, not the value that `i` held when the code was run**

The solution is simple: break the closure by passing `i` as a parameter to a function:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    (function(i){
         $("input[value='"+ i +"']").each(function() {
            $(this).on('change', function() {
                var that = this;
                $("input[value='"+i+"']").each(function() {             //<--
                    if($(this).attr('name') != $(that).attr('name')) {
                        $(this).prop('checked', false);
                    }
                });
            });
         });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Wow, no way! That's it! I'd be interested in reading up a little more on it if you know of any good sources. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed `1` with `i`, now your code is like

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    $("input[value='"+i+"']").each(function() {                     //<--
        $(this).on('change', function() {
            var that = this;
            $("input[value='"+i+"']").each(function() {             //<--
                if($(this).attr('name') != $(that).attr('name')) {
                    $(this).prop('checked', false);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

There is no use in iterating the html elements within the `change` event because it has only one element.  Also you're iterating only an individual group instead try to iterate the group like

```
var names = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
for (var i=0; i< names.length; i++) {
  $("input[name='"+names[i]+"']").each(function() { 
.............
.............
```